# How to click a pop up appears in every 60 minutes through Selenium

Tags: selenium

I`m new to Python.I need to automate clicking on a "Activate"button which appears in every 60 minutes.Can I use

`driver.switch_to.alert` method?

or what is the best way?

Thank you

Comment: We need to see that element in order to say how to click on it

Comment: no I don't think that you need to switch to alert at all. if that's not an alert, if it is, well in that case we have to. so can you share HTML or page URL to have a better understanding